# Multiple profiles with Single AD Domain

Tags: active-directory, user-profile, roaming-profile, profile

I have problem with setting up multiple user profiles with single domain controller

I have 3 terminal server for each 3 company and I have single domain controller for all companies(because they all use single mail @company.com). I want to setup 3 different profile settings for each server. So user can login(with single login/pass) to each server but that user will have 3 different profile on each server(not roaming single profile to each server)

is it possible? or how can do it?

Comment: That would be the default behaviour. If you don't have roaming profiles, each machine the user logs on to will have a unique profile

Comment: But it will try to sync each profiles, doesn't it?

Comment: It being? If you don't have a gpo for roaming profiles, or one of the paths in the AD account configured then no it won't